# Blueimp jQuery file upload Regex .doc

Tags: php, regex, file-type, file-manager

I am using the filemanager for images, now we need another one for documents, but we need to restrict to only doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf and some image types.

I have changed the default regex rule, to make the new validation:

```
$this->options['inline_file_types'] = '/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|PDF|JPG|DOC|DOCX)/';

$this->options['accept_file_types'] = '/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|PDF|JPG|DOC|DOCX)/';
```

But this new rule always gives me `Filetype not allowed` on a .doc, xls and xlsx file.

Can someone explain me the regex code to limit to this file extensions or tell me why this one is failing?

Comment: Try changing it to `/\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)/i` and see if it works. Also, are you sure that if the RegEx finds a match for a file name it isn't for *invalid* file types?

Comment: Thanks for the anwser :)
But it's not correct, now all validations fail, except for .docx...

Comment: We also tried to backslash all 'x' thinking that it might some rule associated with the char, but no success. **FileType not allowed** in all files.

Comment: The problem is not with the regex, it's with something else. This regex matches things like `.jpeg` and `.PDF`, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: But that is the regex that validates the files, my regex was validating all but those three, your regex is failing all but .docx
There must be a problem on this line... I just don't know how to create the rule :|